# Smarty, pages in subdirectories

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

i am trying to figure out how to hold pages in subdirectories (categories) using php Smarty template engine.

For instance if my structure is:

```
index.php
category1/page1.php
category2/page2.php
```

etc.

the root index.php is rendering just fine

using the default smarty setup:

```
<?php 
require_once('lib/smtemplate.php');

$data = array(
    'meta_keywords' =>'key1, key2',
    'category' =>'category1'
    );

$tpl = new SMTemplate();
$tpl->render('page', $data);

?>
```

but if i copy it into subdirectory it breaks even if i change to

```
require_once('../lib/smtemplate.php');
```

and i cant find a solution so far.

Appreciate your help.
thx.

Comment: And where are your template files located? What is your code for `SMTemplate`? Are you setting proper `template_dir` property of Smarty object? Have you bothered to read documentation [http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.template.dir.tpl ] before asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a basepath:

```
define("BASEPATH", "/var/www/yoursite/");
```

And include like this:

```
require_once(BASEPATH.'lib/smtemplate.php');
```

Comment: just tried that and it did not work. Here is the error i get:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'hello.tpl'' in E:\wamp\www\smarty\lib\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php:163 Stack trace: #0 E:\wamp\www\smarty\lib\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php(541): Smarty_Internal_Template->isExisting(true) #1 E:\wamp\www\smarty\lib\smarty\Smarty.class.php(337): Smarty_Internal_Template->getRenderedTemplate() #2 E:\wamp\www\smarty\lib\smtemplate.php(30): Smarty->fetch('hello.tpl')

Comment: or shell i use define("BASEPATH", "/var/www/yoursite/"); through all configuration files as well?

Comment: you should. but there's also trouble with finding "hello.tpl" ... I think the best sollution is "fix your paths" :D

Comment: my root index.php file renders just fine with hello.tpl so i just cant believe Smarty has nothing to manage pages from subdirectories.

Comment: If you've set up things to load from relative paths, i'm afraid you'll have a problem. That's always a thing with including from different subdirs, sorry, but that's how it is.... Goes for you template_c dir too for instance....

Comment: perfect, changing paths solves an issue. Although is it normal that now i get a following notice on pages: Notice: Constant SMARTY_DIR already defined in E:\wamp\www\smarty\lib\smarty\smtemplate.php on line 6